# IdentityServer4 Silent Renew Manually without client library

Tags: identityserver4, openid-connect

I'm writting authentication for flutter, which doesn't have direct access to any of the js clients so I'm trying to parse all of the stuff myself for silent renew. I'm having a number of problems and I can't find anyone that has done it so I figured I'd ask here:

1. When I create my iframe for silent renew I use the check_session path.  This works fine, and I can send in my post message of " <session_state>". However 100% of the time I get back a response message of event.data == "changed".  What am I doing wrong here?
2. When I do try and create a renew without prompt, I can't figure out what to put into the hidden iframe as the URL to make it work. The client uses code flow by default so I'm passing a url that looks like this:

https://localhost:44401/connect/authorize?client_id=Admin&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A51190%2Fcallback.html&response_type=code%20token&scope=openid+profile+email+offline_access&code_challenge_method=S256&code_challenge=&prompt=none&state=

This always returns with login_required. I tried id id_token for the response_type but no dice there either. I just get a massively long error and it says that the grant_type is invalid in the console for identity server.

So what's the trick to getting this working?